# Exception in reading a binary file

Tags: java, ioexception

I am getting this exception. Is it because I am not catching them?

```
 java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2577)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1315)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at ReadStudentRecord.readRecord(ReadStudentRecord.java:34)
at ReadStudentRecordTest.main(ReadStudentRecordTest.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

This is my class that reads a binary file:

```
 import java.io.*;


public class ReadStudentRecord {

private ObjectInputStream input;

public void openFile() {

    try {
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("student.dat"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
} // end of open file method

public void readRecord() {

    Q4 student;

    System.out.println("Student Name\t\t Student average Mark");
    try {

        while (true) {


            student = (Q4) input.readObject();

            System.out.println(student.getStudentName() + "\t\t\t" + student.averageMark(student.getMark()));

                 }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

}// end of readRecord method

public void closeFile() {
    try // close file and exit
    {
        if (input != null)
            input.close();
        System.exit(0);
    } // end try
    catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.err.println("Error closing file.");
        System.exit(1);
    } // end catch
} // end method closeFile
} // end of class
```

It works fine, except that I get the above exception, which I have no idea what might be causing it.
I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading objects from the file in an infinite loop.

```
while (true) {
    student = (Q4) input.readObject();
        ...
}
```

Eventually the stream reaches the end of the file, but you still ask for more objects, and that's why the exception is thrown.

---

A possible solution, would be to catch the EOFException, meaning that no more objects exist.

```
try {
    while (true) {
        student = (Q4) input.readObject();
            ...
    }
}
catch (EOFException eof) {
    // Reached end of file. Do anything here, if you want.
    // Or else, just ignore the end of file, and proceed out of the block.
}
finally {
    // Some other stuff.
    // Do not forget to close the stream.
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: @afsantos You can't use `!= null` since readObject will throw an exception, not return `null` on EOF. I think you are thinking of `BufferedReader readLine()` which does return `null` on EOF. OP is using `ObjectInputStream`, not `BufferedReader`.

Comment: @xagyg Indeed, you are right. I've upvoted your answer, and will update mine to reflect the alternative, which is catching the exception.

Comment: lol, I just submitted the alternative before I saw your comment - great minds! ;)

Comment: @afsantos but your answer is still worthy - adds value - kudos for finally block & tip about closing the stream! Good practice.

Comment: Just to make it water-tight, I would do this ... `finally { try { if (input != null) input.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore exception on attempt to clean up, we're done with it anyway */ } }`

Comment: @xagyg I usually do that second try-block too, but I figured it could be a little confusing to the OP, since he seems not to be too comfortable yet with this. But it is a great suggestion nonetheless!

Comment: catch (EOFException endOfFileException) {
   return; // end of file was reached
  } // end catch is the way to go and it s working now

Comment: @CYBERSIX Glad to hear that you got it to work. If your problems for this question are solved, do not forget to accept the answer that most helped you, so that other users with the same problem may spot it easily.

Answer (score 1):

**Preferably**

Replace

```
while (true)
```

with

```
while (input.available() > 0)
```

**Alternatively**, add this *IMMEDIATELY BEFORE* `catch (IOException e)` in `readRecord`:

```
} catch (EOFException e) {
  // EOF reached
}
```

Comment: Nice mention, about catching `EOFException` before any other `IOException`!

Comment: now it s not giving me anything in return when i replace the while(true) with while (input.available > 0 ) no exception error though